Cannot change textColor of background events in fullcalendar
I am using fullcalendar.io v6 in my vue app with normal events and background events. However I want to change the textColor, which works with normal events perfectly but the background events doesn´t change unless I remove display: 'background'. How can I customize the textcolor of my background events?

 {
    task_id: 2,
    title: 'Test Time event',
    start: '2024-06-10T15:00:00',
    end: '2024-06-10T16:00:00',
    display: 'background',
    backgroundColor: '#ff9f89',
    borderColor: '#ff9f89', 
    textColor: 'green'
  }


Have you tried to select it with CSS?

From docs - The color of background events can be manipulated by targeting the fc-bg-event className, one of your own custom classNames provided by the Event Object’s className property, or by explicitly specifying a color with each Event Object’s or Event Source’s color or backgroundColor properties.

some HTML and a runnable snippet example might help clarify your question more perhaps.

The Background Events documentation says:

The color of background events can be manipulated by targeting the
fc-bg-event className, one of your own custom classNames provided by
the Event Object’s className property, or by explicitly specifying a
color with each Event Object’s or Event Source’s color or
backgroundColor properties.

Since you can target background events using CSS, you can set the CSS color property for the background event class, for instance like this:
.fc-bg-event
{
  color: green;
}

If you need to target a specific event or group of events, then as the documentation says you could do this by making your own class name and assigning that to the event(s). For example:
.bg-event-blue-text
{
  color: blue;
}

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/pomWwVv

References :
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
It can be done by two ways :

using event object color options


In your code modify json key textColor to color
Example :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78710222/15462731


using event object className option



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new FullCalendar.Calendar(
    document.getElementById('calendar'), {
      initialDate: '2024-07-05',
      initialView: 'timeGridDay',
      slotDuration: "00:15:00",
      slotMinTime: '10:00',
      events: [{
          id: 1,
          title: "Demo 1",
          className: "event-green",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T10:00:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T10:15:00"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Demo 2",
          className: "event-blue",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T10:15:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T10:30:00"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Demo 3",
          className: "event-orange",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T10:30:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T10:45:00"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "Demo 1",
          className: "event-green",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T11:00:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T11:15:00"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          title: "Demo 2",
          className: "event-blue",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T11:15:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T11:30:00"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          title: "Demo 3",
          className: "event-orange",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T11:30:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T11:45:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ).render();
});
.event-green {
  background-color:#DCFFB7;
}

.event-blue {
  background-color:#D9F2DB;
}

.event-orange {
  background-color:#F7A774;
}
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.14/index.global.min.js'></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>



